# How to filter in graphql for following?

Tags: graphql

I'm new to graphql. My question structure is

```
questions {
    nodes {
      content
      states {
        nodes {
          name
        }
      }
      subjects {
        nodes {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How do I display content from questions such that subjects' name is Maths and states name is New York.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have something like,

```
filter: {
      questions: {
        content: { name : { eq: "Maths" }}
        states:  { name : { eq : "New York" }}
      }
    }
```

Refer the sample from [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#filtering-on-multiple-fields)